# What is ?: operator

Tags: javascript

I found this in a material-ui example:

```
type ProvidedProps = {
  classes: Object,
  theme?: Object,
};
```

What does ?: mean?

Comment: It means optional

Comment: It simply means that it's optional.

Comment: This is Typescript (?), not ECMAScript.

Comment: This is typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160785/discussion-on-question-by-amon-tamas-what-is-operator).

Answer (score 1):

> ## `?` Following a parameter or property, means that it is optional

Have a read of the [Advanced Types Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) [Optionals and Defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)

This blog post explains the uses of optionals a bit clearer than the official documentation: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/functions.html#optional-parameters

Comment: *"it basically just adds `| undefined` after"* – nnnnno. It's only to satisfy the type system. E.g. `let o: ProvidedProps = {classes: {}}` would fail the static type checker if `theme` was not optional. That's all. It has no bearing on the resulting Javascript. A non-existent property is `undefined` in Javascript anyway without needing to add anything.